# Why visibility is not set after action?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use Visibility to show and hide my container. The first container contains sign in button, sign up button, and forgot password button. And the second container has email textformfield. password textformfield, and sign in button.

What i want to do is; when i click the sign in button in first container, the second container will be visible for me to fill up my credentials to sign in. But currently, when i click the sign in button nothing happens. Why is that? Am i missing something here?

```
class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  _StartPageState createState() => new _StartPageState();
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _toDoVisibility = true;
    bool _signInVisibility = false;

    void _showSignIn(){
      _signInVisibility = true;
      setState(() {
        _toDoVisibility = false;
        _signInVisibility = true;
      });
    }

    void _showToDo(){
      setState(() {
        _signInVisibility = false ;
        _toDoVisibility = true;
      });
    }

    final _toDo = Visibility(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: deco.gradient,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonTheme(
                  child: CustomButtonOutline(text: constant.signIn, onPressed: _showSignIn),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                ButtonTheme(
                  child: CustomButtonOutline(text: constant.signUp, onPressed: _showToDo),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
            ButtonTheme(
              child: CustomButtonOutlineNoBorder(text: constant.forgotPassword, onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => null));
              }),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      maintainSize: true,
      maintainAnimation: true,
      maintainState: true,
      visible: _toDoVisibility,
    );

    final _signIn = Visibility(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 20.0, 30.0, 0.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: constant.email),
              style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: constant.password),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            CustomButtonOutline(text: constant.signIn, onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => null));
            }),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      maintainSize: true,
      maintainAnimation: true,
      maintainState: true,
      visible: _signInVisibility,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => print('something'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          _toDo,
          _signIn,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your visibility booleans in the State class but outside the build method like this:

```
class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
    bool _toDoVisibility = true;
    bool _signInVisibility = false;
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    }
}
```